# What is the syntax of keybinds.settings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cloud9-ide

What is the syntax of the keybinds.settings? I am a vim user, and I would ultimately like to:

- bind shift-j to go down 8 lines (nnoremap J 8j)
- the same with k (nnoremak J 8k)
- Use , as a "leader", i.e. I would like to bind ",b" to "build", and perhaps ",g" to run "ghci file-name" in a terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keybinding.settings file works only for cloud9 commands for now, for customizing vim commands you will have to use init script (see `Open Your Init Script item` in `Cloud9` menu)

You can use following snippet

```
require(["plugins/c9.ide.ace.keymaps/vim/keymap"], function(vim) {
    var defaultKeymap = vim.aceKeyboardHandler.defaultKeymap;
    function ideCommand() { services.commands.exec(this.name); }
    function map(keys, action, context) {
        var mapping;
        if (!action) {
            return defaultKeymap.forEach(function(x) {
                if (x.keys == keys) {
                    x.defaultKeys = keys;
                    x.keys = "";
                }
            });
        } else if (/^c9:/.test(action)) {
            var commandName = action.substr(3);
            mapping = {
                keys: keys, type: "action", action: "aceCommand",
                actionArgs: { exec: ideCommand, name: commandName }
            };
        } else {
            mapping = { keys: keys, type: "keyToKey", toKeys: action };
        }

        if (context)
            mapping.context = context;
        mapping.user = true;
        defaultKeymap.unshift(mapping);
    }
    map("J", "8j", "normal");
    map("K", "8k", "normal");
    map(",", ""); // remove default mapping of ,
    map(",b", "c9:build", "normal");
    map(",g", "c9:run", "normal");
});
```

note that for `,g` you need to create ghci runner, see https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html for details.