# How do I differentiate between normal mode and insert mode in Cloud9 keybindings?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Cloud9 supports vim mode, which makes it very nice to use for vim lovers. I can't find any way to differentiate between insert mode, normal mode and visual (select) mode in the key bindings. Is it possible? If so, how?

---

<sup>If anybody wants to point me in the direction of some Cloud9 hacking documentation in the comments I'd appreciate it. I can find very little.</sup>

Comment: There isn't currently a way via the menu's. Though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331865/what-is-the-syntax-of-keybinds-settings/27334695#27334695 has some information on how to hack around it.